# GoLand save password in a "Run with sudo" configuration

Tags: jetbrains-ide, archlinux, goland

I'm running a program inside GoLand that requires root privileges and I'm trying to configure the IDE to save the sudo password so I don't have to constantly type it in the dialog prompt. I've set it up in the Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Passwords to use the "In native Keychain". I have a gnome-keyring deamon running with a "Default Keyring" and no password. However the sudo password prompt always appears when I try to run it.

I've also tried the "In KeePass" setting, but it doesn't work either.

Does GoLand support saving the sudo password and if so - any suggestions on what can be done to get it to work with gnome-keyring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GoLand never asks a user for a password. It always delegates this task to an operating system. This means that the IDE doesn't know the password, so it can't store it anywhere. Depending on the OS, one can configure `sudo` to skip a password check though it can be insecure.